# Use XML child node as label in Spark list itemRenderer

Tags: xml, apache-flex, label, itemrenderer

In ActionScript, I whittle down my XML to a series of nodes, all formed like this:

```
<option letter="A">
    <letter>A</letter>
    <response>Thank you</response>
    <posFeed>Excellent</posFeed>
    <negFeed>Terrible</negFeed>
    <score>-1</score>
    <elimOptions>B</elimOptions>
</option>
```

When I set this series as the dataProvider for my Spark list that uses a custom item renderer with a Spark label, I set the label.text={data}, which displays each full set of nodes as a list item.

If I don't want to whittle the XML down to just the  nodes beforehand (I'd like the full set intact for other functions I have to perform), how can I set just the response node to be the data to use for the label in the itemRenderer? I tried setting the label text={data.response}, but that doesn't work (a full set of nodes still appears as each list item.

Comment: `label.text = xml.response.text();`

Comment: On the spark label, I currently have text={data}, and have tried text={data.response}. I then tried text={data.xml.response.text()} and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:XML id="data">
        <options>
            <option letter="A">
                <letter>A</letter>
                <response>Thank you</response>
                <posFeed>Excellent</posFeed>
                <negFeed>Terrible</negFeed>
                <score>-1</score>
                <elimOptions>B</elimOptions>
            </option>
            <option letter="B">
                <letter>B</letter>
                <response>Thank you B</response>
                <posFeed>Excellent B</posFeed>
                <negFeed>Terrible B</negFeed>
                <score>-1</score>
                <elimOptions>B</elimOptions>
            </option>
        </options>
    </fx:XML>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:List labelField="response">
    <s:dataProvider>
        <s:XMLListCollection source="{data.option}" />
    </s:dataProvider>
</s:List>
```

I should add that when I did this, I didn't have any trouble using a custom item renderer:

```
<s:List itemRenderer="DataItemRenderer">
    <s:dataProvider>
        <s:XMLListCollection source="{data.option}" />
    </s:dataProvider>
</s:List>

<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                autoDrawBackground="true">

    <s:Label text="{data.response}"/>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Comment: Odd. It doesn't work for me. My itemRenderer still shows the entire option node with child nodes, not just the response node text. My dataProvider value traces to be just the set of option nodes as a list collection and I set the text of the label in my itemRenderer to {data.response} and...no dice.

Comment: I should add, I can't form my XML in the MXML. I'm having to bring it in from a server. There's a variable that holds the XMLListCollection of the list of option nodes, but it's not called "data."

Comment: It should not be any different if the XML comes from MXML or from the server.  It is typed the exact same way.  Do you know for sure that your item renderer is being called?  You can put a breakpoint in the binding and check out your data variable from there. The breakpoint will fire when the binding evaluates.  You can look at different values in the "Expressions" window dynamically at debug time.  If you still can't figure it out, I think you should post your MXML and a complete document-form snipit of your XML so we can evaluate.

Comment: There was just an issue with how my itemRenderer function was written. I rewrote it and everything's fine. Thanks for your help